# What pool miners exist that can mine RandomX?

Tags: mining, random-x

In a couple weeks from now, Monero will start using the RandomX PoW algorithm, replacing the current Cryptonight-R. What are the current pool miner software that may be used to mine with this particular algorithm, so that a current miner may use to continue mining after the switch ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[XMRig](https://github.com/xmrig/xmrig) is the miner with the most actively developed RandomX implementation. It can also [seamlessly switch](https://github.com/xmrig/xmrig/blob/master/doc/ALGORITHMS.md) from CN/R to RandomX when the network updates if in your pool config you set the property `coin` to `"coin": "monero"`. Aside from mining to a pool with XMRig, you can also solo mine against your Monero daemon. This offers a performance improvement over simply mining directly with the daemon's built-in miner.

There is also a version of [xmr-stak](https://github.com/fireice-uk/xmr-stak/tree/1.0.0-rx) for RandomX mining, though it should be noted, they simply copied the RandomX code directly from XMRig. Whether this miner supports automatic switching from CN/R or whether the developers plan any unique features w.r.t. RandomX, I cannot answer.